# Need to implement pagination for negative pagenumber in c#

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, linq

I need to implement pagination using c# Linq skip and take

If I get negative page number as -1 and page size as 5, I need return last 5 items

Total record count 15

Page size is 5 and page number is -1

var result = records.skip(10).Take(5)

Similarly I have to do it if pagenumber is -2, -3

Comment: Where is the problem ? `IQueryable<Whatever> query = ....` `if(pageNumber < 0)  { pageNumber=-pageNumber; query.OrderBy(Prolly desc ... whatever means "last"); }` ... rest of the stuff should be the same(calculate skip) and `query = query.Skip(skip).Take(pageSize)` then materialize `query`

Comment: Order by should not be applied. Should be done without applying order by or reverse

Comment: "Should be done without applying order by or reverse" - is this a homework question?

Comment: of course it should be `query = query.OrderBy...` ... I don't understand why you can't use `OrderBy` it's natural here ... fx `...query.OrderBy(x=>x.IssueDate);` for positive `pageNumber` and `...query.OrderByDescending(x=>x.IssueDate);` for negative ... rest works as without this requirements

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code should help you:

```
///<summary>
///Returns a page from the end of the collection
///</summary>
///<param name="source">The intial collection</param>
///<param name="index">Negative index (-1, -2, -3...)</param>
///<param name="pageSize">Number of elements in a page</param>
static IEnumerable<T> TakeNegative<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, int index, int pageSize)
{
    return source.Skip(source.Count() + pageSize * (index)).Take(pageSize);
}
```

It returns first `pageSize` (i.e. 5) results, if the page `index` is out of the limits. If this is not a supposed behaviour, you can add some condition checks and fix it.

Comment: @resrrectiontent thanks for response this solution seems to be working for the above case but in the below case it’s not below case if source count is 30 and index -4 and pagesize is 8